# Paint (Windows 8)

Tags: transparency

What is "Any transparency will be lost if you save this picture. do you want to continue?" because after I'm edit PNG pictures on paint,still appear the questions about "Any transparency will be lost if you save this picture. do you want to continue?"

Answer (score 3):

Paint does not support tranparency. You can see at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint). So when you save the image, the transparent color becomes solid.

I recommend you [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org.es/). It is free and is more powerful. Or you can see another options on answers of [how-to-create-transparent-image-in-ms-paint](https://superuser.com/questions/498481/how-to-create-transparent-image-in-ms-paint)

Answer (score 1):

Besides of RGB(Red-Green-Blue) properties of color, PNG files may contain one more property - Alpha channel that keep information about transparency. For example if you draw in [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) solid black circle on white background then regardless where you put this image on top of any other - background of black circle will still the same - white, but if you choosed transparent background instead of white, then when you mix it with other images - the only black circle will be constant, background would be filled with mixed image. Transparency can be adjusted as one need by changing opacity.
So, windows's paint warn you that after editing you will loose alpha channel(transparency).

Answer (score 1):

PNG files can have transparent parts, but Paint does not support this so will remove the transparency of your images if you try to use it. If you need to edit PNGs with transparency I suggest using a different program, GIMP has been recommended but Paint.NET is a more similar replacement with less learning curve.